# How to export Nagios data into CSV?

Tags: database, export-to-csv, nagios

I am a newbie and I am doing this for my project. I am able to install and monitor nagios successfully. But I am required to export these data into csv. Can anyone help me in this?

Thank you so much xx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the `host_perfdata_file` and `service_perfdata_file` directives in your `nagios.cfg` configuration file to output performance data to the specified file path in the format specified by the `host_perfdata_file_template` and `service_perfdata_file_template` directive.

> **Writing Performance Data To Files**
>
> You can have Nagios write all host and service performance data
>   directly to text files using the `host_perfdata_file` and
>   `service_perfdata_file` options. The format in which host and service
>   performance data is written to those files is determined by the
>   `host_perfdata_file_template` and `service_perfdata_file_template`
>   options.
>
> An example file format template for service performance data might
>   look like this:
>
> ```
> service_perfdata_file_template=[SERVICEPERFDATA]\t$TIMET$\t$HOSTNAME$\t$SERVICEDESC$\t$SERVICEEXECUTIONTIME$\t$SERVICELATENCY$\t$SERVICEOUTPUT$\t$SERVICEPERFDATA$
> ```
>
> By default, the text files will be opened in "append" mode. If you
>   need to change the modes to "write" or "non-blocking read/write"
>   (useful when writing to pipes), you can use the
>   host_perfdata_file_mode and service_perfdata_file_mode options.
>
> Additionally, you can have Nagios periodically execute commands to
>   periocially process the performance data files (e.g. rotate them)
>   using the `host_perfdata_file_processing_command` and
>   `service_perfdata_file_processing_command` options. The interval at
>   which these commands are executed are governed by the
>   `host_perfdata_file_processing_interval` and
>   `service_perfdata_file_processing_interval` options, respectively.

*Source: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/perfdata.html*

> **Performance Data Processing Option**
>
> ```
> Format:   process_performance_data=<0/1>
> Example:  process_performance_data=1
> This value determines whether or not Nagios will process host and service check performance data.
>
> 0 = Don't process performance data (default)
> 1 = Process performance data
> ```
>
> **Host Performance Data Processing Command**
>
> ```
> Format:   host_perfdata_command=<command>
> Example:  host_perfdata_command=process-host-perfdata
> ```
>
> This option allows you to specify a command to be run after every host
>   check to process host performance data that may be returned from the
>   check. The command argument is the short name of a command definition
>   that you define in your object configuration file. This command is
>   only executed if the process_performance_data option is enabled
>   globally and if the process_perf_data directive in the host definition
>   is enabled.
>
> **Service Performance Data Processing Command**
>
> ```
> Format:   service_perfdata_command=<command>
> Example:  service_perfdata_command=process-service-perfdata
> ```
>
> This option allows you to specify a command to be run after every
>   service check to process service performance data that may be returned
>   from the check. The command argument is the short name of a command
>   definition that you define in your object configuration file. This
>   command is only executed if the process_performance_data option is
>   enabled globally and if the process_perf_data directive in the service
>   definition is enabled.
>
> **Host Performance Data File**
>
> ```
> Format:   host_perfdata_file=<file_name>
> Example:  host_perfdata_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/host-perfdata.dat
> ```
>
> This option allows you to specify a file to which host performance
>   data will be written after every host check. Data will be written to
>   the performance file as specified by the host_perfdata_file_template
>   option. Performance data is only written to this file if the
>   process_performance_data option is enabled globally and if the
>   process_perf_data directive in the host definition is enabled.
>
> **Service Performance Data File**
>
> ```
> Format:   service_perfdata_file=<file_name>
> Example:  service_perfdata_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/service-perfdata.dat
> ```
>
> This option allows you to specify a file to which service performance
>   data will be written after every service check. Data will be written
>   to the performance file as specified by the
>   service_perfdata_file_template option. Performance data is only
>   written to this file if the process_performance_data option is enabled
>   globally and if the process_perf_data directive in the service
>   definition is enabled.
>
> **Host Performance Data File Template**
>
> ```
> Format:   host_perfdata_file_template=<template>
> Example:  host_perfdata_file_template=[HOSTPERFDATA]\t$TIMET$\t$HOSTNAME$\t$HOSTEXECUTIONTIME$\t$HOSTOUTPUT$\t$HOSTPERFDATA$
> ```
>
> This option determines what (and how) data is written to the host
>   performance data file. The template may contain macros, special
>   characters (\t for tab, \r for carriage return, \n for newline) and
>   plain text. A newline is automatically added after each write to the
>   performance data file.
>
> **Service Performance Data File Template**
>
> ```
> Format:   service_perfdata_file_template=<template>
> Example:  service_perfdata_file_template=[SERVICEPERFDATA]\t$TIMET$\t$HOSTNAME$\t$SERVICEDESC$\t$SERVICEEXECUTIONTIME$\t$SERVICELATENCY$\t$SERVICEOUTPUT$\t$SERVICEPERFDATA$
> ```
>
> This option determines what (and how) data is written to the service
>   performance data file. The template may contain macros, special
>   characters (\t for tab, \r for carriage return, \n for newline) and
>   plain text. A newline is automatically added after each write to the
>   performance data file.

*Source: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/configmain.html#process_performance_data*

**NOTE:** If you've followed the directions to setup [pnp4nagios](https://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/config#bulk_mode) in "Bulk Mode", you've probably already done this. In that case, you just need to refer to the path you specified in `host_perfdata_file` and `service_perfdata_file`.  But if not, here's how you do it for pnp4nagios:

> Processing of performance data has to be enabled in nagios.cfg
>
> ```
>  process_performance_data=1
> ```
>
> Additionally some new directives are required
>
> ```
> #
> # service performance data
> #
> service_perfdata_file=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/service-perfdata
> service_perfdata_file_template=DATATYPE::SERVICEPERFDATA\tTIMET::$TIMET$\tHOSTNAME::$HOSTNAME$\tSERVICEDESC::$SERVICEDESC$\tSERVICEPERFDATA::$SERVICEPERFDATA$\tSERVICECHECKCOMMAND::$SERVICECHECKCOMMAND$\tHOSTSTATE::$HOSTSTATE$\tHOSTSTATETYPE::$HOSTSTATETYPE$\tSERVICESTATE::$SERVICESTATE$\tSERVICESTATETYPE::$SERVICESTATETYPE$
> service_perfdata_file_mode=a
> service_perfdata_file_processing_interval=15
> service_perfdata_file_processing_command=process-service-perfdata-file
>
> #
> # host performance data starting with Nagios 3.0
> # 
> host_perfdata_file=/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/host-perfdata
> host_perfdata_file_template=DATATYPE::HOSTPERFDATA\tTIMET::$TIMET$\tHOSTNAME::$HOSTNAME$\tHOSTPERFDATA::$HOSTPERFDATA$\tHOSTCHECKCOMMAND::$HOSTCHECKCOMMAND$\tHOSTSTATE::$HOSTSTATE$\tHOSTSTATETYPE::$HOSTSTATETYPE$
> host_perfdata_file_mode=a
> host_perfdata_file_processing_interval=15
> host_perfdata_file_processing_command=process-host-perfdata-file
> ```

*Source: https://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/config#bulk_mode*

### **EDIT:** Here's an easier way to get generate CSV data on-demand.

- Browse to http:///nagios/cgi-bin/avail.cgi
- Fill out the steps of the wizard.
- Be sure to check the "Output in CSV Format" checkbox on the 3rd screen.
- Click "Create Availability Report!" button.
- CSV file will be generated and downloaded in your browser.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @mwfearnley I think it's JSON, but I'm not in front of a Nagios deployment where I can try it out right now.

Comment: I know this is old, but for anyone who happens to read it: one problem with the perfdata approach is that the file won't contain any information for checks that do not publish performance data fields.

Comment: @Luke404 that's pretty obvious since that's what perfdata means, it's optional data supplied by the plugins themselves. What else would you expect the file to contain? If you're looking for current data (like states), this is already available from Nagios via MK Livestatus for example.